# How do I know if a certain blueprint will be discussed at UDS?

Tags: uds

There's already [a long list of blueprints](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric) registered for Oneiric. How do I know whether or not certain blueprints I'd like to follow will be discussed at the UDS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That list of blueprints are ones that have been proposed for "Oneiric" the series in general. You want this list, as it's the approved list of topics for UDS:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/sprints/uds-o

Prior to UDS this list grows, so I bookmark the page. You can subscribe to the specific blueprint if you want to follow along, and [check the schedule](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-o/) to see when it's actually going to happen if you want to participate remotely.